# Активация бота в дискорд

Tags: python, cmd, бот, discord

Я начинающий в сфере "Питона" и часто сталкиваюсь с подобными ошибками. Написал бота, начал активировать в cmb командой 'c:\games\discord.py', а он не работает=/. Код написан правильно. Помогите пожалуйста!

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))

client = MyClient()
client.run('тут был токен')
```

вот и сам код

Comment: Если бот не работает, то не думаю, что код написан правильно. Стоит добавить код в вопрос

Comment: `начал активировать в cmb командой 'c:\games\discord.py'` python-файлы запускаются командой `python "путь_к_файлу"`. Попробуйте `python "c:\games\discord.py"`

Comment: Ошибка, 'File "c:\games\discord.py" line 7 async def on_message(self, message):

Comment: а так же сама ошибка: unindent does not match any outher indentatuon level

Answer (score 3):

зачем что-то усложнять классами?
просто и ясно

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
token = "сюда токен "
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.') #инициализируем бота с вашим префиксом 
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("+")
client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    @Client.event
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
    @Client.event
    async def on_message(self, message):
        print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))

client = MyClient()
client.run('тут был токен')
```

Попробуйте так. А вообще Евгений прав, если бот не запускается, значит код написан не правильно, вы же его слова подтвердили сообщением, в котором указали на ошибку.

Comment: опять ошибка : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\games\discord.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
  File "c:\games\discord.py", line 3, in <module>
    class MyClient(discord.Client):
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'discord' has no attribute 'Client'
 (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: Я не могу вам дать точный ответ на ваш вопрос, т.к. я делал бота не через класс. То что я вам предложил попробовать - мои догадки, не более. Если вы пишете бота по каким-либо урокам, перепроверьте все еще раз))